# Case-insensitive comparing elements from two lists that can be strings or ints

Tags: python, list

```
def listCompare(list1 , list2) :
    num_equal = sum(x == y for x, y in zip(list1, list2))
    if len(list1) < len(list2):
        matchPerc = ((num_equal)/len(list2))*100
    else :
        matchPerc = ((num_equal)/len(list1))*100
return f'The lists match by {matchPerc}%'


list1 = [1,2.0,3,'savvy']

list2 = [1,2,3,'Savvy']

print(listCompare(list1, list2))
```

I just cant figure out how to make the comparison case insensitive for a list containing a combination of ints and strings.

Comment: check type and if type is string use lower?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Check the type of the element and `lower()` strings? Or convert everything to a lowercase string before you compare?

Comment: more of a bonus question but you could call it homework.

Comment: when i use lower after checking type it says 'int' has no attribute 'lower' but works fine when the list contains only strings.

Comment: Well don't do `lower()` if it's an int!

Comment: let me rephrase that. I want to use lower() on the string in the list. But it doesnt work when the list is a combination of ints and strings.

Comment: @AijinShinra Should the string `"2"` be considered equal to the int `2` and the float `2.0`?

Comment: If you want to reduce the number of lines of code, I would recommend this style `matchPerc = num_equal / min(len(list1), len(list2))*100`.

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution would be to iterate through the list and check if the element an alphabet. If yes, then convert to lower case. Something like this:

```
for i in range(len(list2)):
    if str(list2[i]).isalpha():
        list2[i]=list2[i].lower()
```

After this you can continue calculating num_equal. I tried and I got 100%

Answer (score 0):

To make the comparison case-insensitive, you could do it a couple of different ways:

1. Convert everything to a lowercase string before comparing

```
num_equal = sum(str(x).lower() == str(y).lower() for x, y in zip(list1, list2))
```

This breaks when there are floats and ints that don't convert to the same string (like `2` and `2.0`)

2. You could check the type of `x` and `y` before deciding what to do:

```
num_equal = 0
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    if isinstance(x, str) and isinstance(y, str):
        num_equal += (x.lower() == y.lower())
    else:
        num_equal += (x == y)
```

With `list1` and `list2` as you defined in your question, this gives `num_equal = 4`

Although I don't agree with the "everything in one line of python" mindset, if you *really* wanted to write this in one line, you could do:

```
num_equal = sum(x.lower() == y.lower() if isinstance(x, str) and isinstance(y, str) else x == y for x, y in zip(list1, list2))
```

Comment: First approach would be wrong (eg. str(2) is '2', and str(2.0) is '2.0', they should be equal). I think the best ways is to format items in lists, and to compare using 'sum' in one line code if you stick to it

Comment: @yixuan That's why there's a strike through it and a sentence saying "This breaks when..."